# Publish Over SSH not respecting Remote Directory on Windows Server

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2016, jenkins

As part of a Jenkins build process, I'd like to run a powershell script on the target machine. The target and source machines are both running Windows Server 2016.

I have a SSH configuration set up to the target machine. I'm using the Publish Over SSH plugin for this. The first thing I noticed is that the SSH configuration seems to not respect my remote directory. I have the following for the remote directory `../../inetpub/wwwroot/MyProject/bin`. I've tested this path in an SSH session outside of Jenkins and it takes me where I need to be.

However, if I run `echo %CD%` as the command in Exec Command, it returns `C:/Users/Administrator`. Also, if I try accessing anything in the path `../../inetpub/wwwroot/MyProject/bin`, I get file not found issues.

I'm able to run the powershell file if I provide the full path, but I would like to have the remote directory put me in the correct directory, in case anything changes.

Comment: have you tried an absolute path instead of a relative path?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it expects a unix style path. So I can't do `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MyProject/bin`. Is there a way to specify that without the drive letter? I could create a simlink under `C:\Users\Administrator`, but that seems wrong.